# Retrieve List Item Value From Version History Using Powershell

Tags: splistitem, version-history

The scenario is I want to retrieve column values(Item Value) of the list from version history and update only single column of item post.

Currently, I am not able to retrieve item object values but I am able to get Created by the user, Title etc field values.

Can someone please help me with it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean with item object values ? as What ?

Comment: Here I mean is - from version history data I am not able to get field values. I need last modified values of fields. I hope this helps you.

Comment: In version history, I think the last modified value is the last version record value ! correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Yes but I don't want to update last modified values of all field. I want to update just one column value so that I am not able to do.

Comment: There's a function "UpdateOverwriteVersion()" that overwrites the last version record via C# I will post the full code in the answer if it helps you please upvote and set it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can achieve your scenario via Server-side Object Model C# to can update a column value in the Version history.

**Code:**

```
SPSite site = new SPSite("http://sharepointsite/subsite");
SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb();
SPList list = web.Lists["My List"];
web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
foreach (SPListItem item in list.Items)
{
  item["Modified"] = "Set the date";
  item["Created"] = "Set the date";
  item["Editor"]="itemCreatedUser";
  item.UpdateOverwriteVersion();
}
```

**Note :**

> It is impossible to update the Modified By values in the Version
>   History. The data of version history is stored in the SQL database,
>   but it is not recommended to edit the data in the database.

Comment: You are welcome, Is the problem has been solved ?